# Download large zip file from FTP server with R

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

I want to download an 8Gb zip file from FTP server to local disk in R, and I have to input username and password.

I've searched many solutions here and in google but most are using `getBinaryURL` from `RCurl` like the following:

```
bin <- getBinaryURL("ftp://foo.com/file.zip",
                    userpwd="<username>:<password>")
con <- file("file.zip", open = "wb")
writeBin(bin, con)
close(con)
```

But I can't allocate 8G memory on my machine to save `bin`, I need to save it directly to disk, how can I do that?

Comment: why not just make a `system` or `system2` call to the `curl` binary directly? Also, this: https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/44

Comment: Shouldn't `httr::write_disk` avoid RAM restriction?